# Python regex with optional substrings

Tags: python, regex

So I have text from which I'd like to extract some key-value pairs. I want to do this in the most efficient way possible, so I was thinking of regex. But I don't understand how to say "if this key exists - take its value, and if not, continue taking other existing key-pair values".

So let's say I have this text, and I want to extract only `Value3` and `Value4`:

```
Placeholder1
String: Key1=Value1, Key2=Value2, Key3=Value3, Key4=Value4
Placeholder2
String: Key1=Value1, Key2=Value2, Key3=Value3, Key4=Value4
```

For this run I just want the first appearance, i.e. right after `Placeholder1`. So I have something like this:

`Placeholder1\s*.*Key3=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*).*Key4=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)`

Which works and gets me `Group 1 = Value3, Group 2 = Value4`. Excellent.
However, if I have the following string without `Key3=Value3`:

```
Placeholder1
String: Key1=Value1, Key2=Value2, Key5=Value5, Key4=Value4
```

My regex of course doesn't work, even though I want it to get me `Key4`. So I thought that putting the groups with a `()?` would work, so that if it exists it will take it, and if not - move on:

`Placeholder1\s*.*(Key3=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*))?.*(Key4=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*))?`

However adding the `?` returns me nothing from the original text where both key-value pairs exist. When I remove the `?` it will work again, but not when `Key3` is missing.

So how do I build a regex that will take the maximum number of key-value pairs that exist in the text?

**PS** - The key-value pairs can appear with/without other key-value pairs between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is almost fine except the greedy expression `.*` just before `Key3` in your regex, as that is causing exhaustive match due to which `.*` eats all it can and doesn't leave `Key3` value for getting captured. Just add `?` after `.*` to make it non-greedy and it will work exactly the way you expected.

`Your regex    : Placeholder1\s*.*Key3=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*).*Key4=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)`

`Modified regex: Placeholder1\s*.*?Key3=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*).*Key4=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)`

See this demo,

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O2lJfm/1/)**

**Edit: If both Key3 and Key4 can be optionally present**

Then you can use this regex,

```
Placeholder1\s*(?:(?!(?:Key[34])).)*(?:Key3=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*))?(?:(?!(?:Key[34])).)*(?:Key4=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*))?
```

**Here is the explanation:**

Although above regex might appear a little complex but explanation to it is indeed quite simple. If you notice, I have just replaced `.` from your original regex with `(?:(?!(?:Key[34])).)`. where later expression is called [tampered greedy dot](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed), which according to the expression will still capture any character but stop capturing as soon as it sees a `Key3` or `Key4` (`[34]` means either `3` or `4` and just one character) and that is what we exactly wanted. We want to capture anything except when it is either `Key3` key or `Key4` key and that's how it works. Feel free if you still have any doubts.

Here just using `.` won't suffice as either its greedy or non-greedy version will either consume all or none characters, hence you need a tempered greedy dot that ignores capturing `Key3` or `Key4`.

Check this updated Demo,

**[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O2lJfm/2/)**

If this works for you, I will add explanation to my regex. (Now added above)

On another simpler note, I feel it will be better to just use these two following regexes to capture `Key3` and `Key4` separately as the regex would be much simpler to write and maintain,

```
Placeholder1[\w\W]*?Key3=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*) (For finding Key3's value)
Placeholder1[\w\W]*?Key4=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*) (For finding Key4's value)
```

One more benefit of this approach you will get is, it will be immune to the order of `Key3` and `Key4` appearing in your string.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But if I change `Key4` to `Key5` in the text, it doesn't capture `Key3`.

Comment: I mean, if `Key4` isn't there, I would still want `Key3` to be captured, but right now it isn't.

Comment: @Cauthon: Ok, if both can be optionally present/absent then you need a little more sophisticated regex. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly, but I'm not sure I really understand it completely. I'd be happy to read an explanation. And you might certainly be right about simply splitting the regex up for each key...

Comment: @Cauthon: Glad it worked for you. Let me add the explanation to my updated regex.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you want to get only key3 and key4, if that's the case
you could use OR operator in regex too the syntax is (|).
so change your regex to `.*Key3=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)|.*Key4=([a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)`
it will try to match any Key3 or Key4 and if not move to next line but also remember to add MULTILINE tag to your regex function call.

Comment: Thanks! This works for the basic example, but I just updated it with a more general one. The `|` works but it also disregards my `Placeholder1` (so it takes both lines of key-value pairs in the example). I just need the pairs from right after the placeholder. How do I let `|` know to only start from the current line and not from the whole text?

Comment: It's a bit tricky but a handy solution is to extract all the line with desired "Placeholder" with a regex like `Placeholder1\n.*` and then try to extract key values using the expression i mentioned earlier without being concerned about the placeholder.